# Protecting dynamic array member of const struct

Tags: c

Consider a `struct` with a dynamic allocated array as a member, for example:

```
struct matrix {
    unsigned cols;
    unsigned rows;
    double* data;
};
```

How can I write a function like `print_matrix(const matrix);` that guarantees the data `data`points to is not modified?

Can I define something like

```
struct const_matrix {
    const unsigned cols;
    const unsigned rows;
    const double* data;
};
```

and then implicitly convert a `struct matrix` to a `struct const_matrix`?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/YbGcLCzN) is a small example why the first version does not work.

Comment: Does `print_matrix(const struct matrix)` not work? Or does the function need to change some of `matrix`'s elements but not `data`? (Which would be weird for a printing-function...)

Comment: @Kninnug It seems this version only protects the value of the pointer `data`, but not the data it points to. It was still changed in an example I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct.  You can define `struct const_matrix` just as you have and then cast to it:

```
void print_matrix(struct const_matrix *m)
{
    // This bad implementation tries to change data.
    // It does not compile.
    m->data[0] = 100;
}
```

To call it, cast from (struct matrix *) to (struct const_matrix *).  For example:

```
{
    struct matrix m;
    m.cols = 4;
    m.rows = 4;
    m.data = calloc(sizeof(double), m.cols*m.rows);

    ...

    print_matrix((struct const_matrix *)&m);
}
```

Note that you must cast the pointer types (i.e. cast from `(struct matrix *)` to `(struct const_matrix *)`, because C will not allow you to cast one structure to another (i.e., casting from `(struct matrix)` to `(struct const_matrix)` is not allowed).

Comment: Is this pointercast guaranteed to be save? (I'm a C++ guy and all I ever hear is "beware of C-style casts".)

Comment: Yes, as long as the structures are identical (except for the "consts").  The consts qualifiers will not affect the size, alignment or packing of the members.  That said, you are making a trade-off: enforcing that print_matrix doesn't misbehave, at the expense of now needing to keep the two structures in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another `const` there:

```
double * const data; // non constant pointer to constant data
```

or even

```
double const * const data; // constant pointer to constant data
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answer addresses his problem.  @Malloc is trying to create an immutable version of his matrix structure.